# wake on lan with android's qpython3

Tags: python-3.x, wake-on-lan

My motherboard is ASUS H81M-E,it connect to a router.
Setting in BIOS:

```
Advanced--Realtek Lan Controller--enabled
        --Realtek Pxe Option Rom--enabled
```

Setting in router:

```
the ip and mac address are binded together
```

I want to wake the pc on lan,router is on,my android phone have installed qpython3,the `startpc.py` is simple :

```
 from wakeonlan import send_magic_packet
 send_magic_packet('my pc's mac')
```

Running from  `qpython3`,the pc can't wake up,how to fix it?

Comment: In the BIOS -> Advanced -> APM Configuration is there an option "Power on by PCI-E/PCI" and if yes, is it enabled or disabled?

Comment: Please write it as a formal answer,i give you the 100 bonus.

Comment: Sorry, only saw your comment now. Will do in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Advanced APM and Enable --> Power On By PCI-E

please find image attached below for reference.

[image: Bios Setting]

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS, there is an option "Power on by PCI-E / PCI" in the subsection "Advanced" -> "APM Configuration".

Make sure this is turned on as it prevents wake on lan if turned off.

Unfortunately, this is not directly documented in the user's manual (https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H81M-A/E8599_H81M-Series.pdf), but the subsection 2.5 gives a good indication on how to get to the advanced section and how it should look like.